# Azure pipeline: unable to start cross-built docker image

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

I have pushed a linux/arm64 image to a docker registry and I am trying to use this image with the container tag in an azure-pipeline. The image seems to be pulled correctly but it can't be executed because the Virtual Machine is ubuntu-20.04 (not the same architecture -->linux/amd64). When I am on my local computer and want to execute this docker image I simply need to run the following command. However, I can't seem to be able to run an emulator before the container tries to execute in the azure job.

```
docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt:qemu-v6.2.0 --install all
```

Here is the azure pipeline that I am trying to run:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: build_container_arm64
    image: my_arm_image
    endpoint: my_endpoint
  
jobs:
- job:
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
  timeoutInMinutes: 240
  container: build_container_arm64
  steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "Hello world"
```

I am wondering if there is a way that I could install or run an emulator before the container tries to execute.

Thanks